# Bootstrap5 icons font-weight

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-icons

I recently updated to bootstrap 5 directly from 3. Yes, I skipped 4.

Thing is, back in 3, I used to do something like this.

```html
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>

<style> i:hover { font-weight: bold; } </style>
```

Now, with bootstrap5's icons, that doesn't work!

Obviously, I'm now using the new icons.

```html
<i class="bi bi-asterisk"></i>

<style> i:hover { font-weight: bold; } </style>
```

But as I said, it doesn't work.

Why? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have been testing the Bootstrap 5 and font-weight did not work with "Bootstrap 5 icon `<i></i>`". But using `-webkit-text-stroke` will be get look like `font-weight` result.

**Please try this.**

```html
    <i class="bi bi-asterisk"></i>
    <style> i:hover { -webkit-text-stroke: 1px; } </style>
```

It work at Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 4):

`font-weight` does not work with the *Bootstrap 5 Icon Font*.

As the [Bootstrap Icon documentation](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#styling) mentions, styling is very limited.

> Styling
> Color can be changed by setting a .text-* class or custom CSS

You can apply a hack by using the [non-standard `-webkit-text-stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke), which will resemble bold text.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .bi-hover-bold:hover {
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px;
  }
</style>

<p>
  <i class="bi-asterisk bi-hover-bold" role="img" aria-label="Required"></i> Bold-like on hover
</p>

<p>
  <i class="bi-asterisk" role="img" aria-label="Required"></i> Normal, for comparison
</p>
```

#### Warning about bold on hover

This hack does not behave the same as real bold, as it does not change the character’s size. Because `font-weight` does change the text flow, it should be avoided on hover, as text might shift or even wrap while hovering.

#### Warnings on Accessibility

See also [Accessibility considerations for Bootstrap Icon](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#accessibility)

If you want to style hover for an element, it indicates that you probably have some interaction bound to it. Interactive elements need to fit several criteria to be usable by people with disabilities or keyboard fans:

- It needs to be obvious that one can interact with it, visually
- That also needs to be indicated by means of the element’s role, like `button` or `link`, to be exposed to assistive technology
- Interaction needs to work with the keyboard as well, being focusable
- To know what activating the element does, it needs an accessible name

For this case it’s best to wrap the icon in a button:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" aria-label=""><i class="bi-asterisk"></i></button>
<style>
  .btn:hover { -webkit-text-stroke: 1px }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple misunderstood concept of font and how they work.
The Icons are made of a font, so the same concept is working here too.

Normally when you set something bold with `font-weight` the browser will not actally just make the font a bit bigger. NO they will replace the complete font with a similar font. As an example: `Aria` to `Aria Bold`. A high quality font should come with atleast 3 or better 6 versions (Light, Normal, Bold x cursive, non-cursive)

When the browser can't find a font for another `font-weight` version , it tries to guess how it should look like. The same with `font-style`.

See the difference in `italic` and `oblique` in the docs as an example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style

So how should your icon letter should look like bold or light? Why did it work on the older bootstrap version? Don't know really. Maybe some font intern settings or css decleration. But one is sure: You should not use this rule for icons (which not support them, FontAwesome supports it btw.).

One similar approach is to use `transform: scale(1.05)` to resize the DOM Element. Using `scale(2)` would double its size.

Comment: Thanks for this! I kind of remember now that I worked with fonts a while back. I did some inspecting and still can't figure out the difference in approach between bootstrap 5 and bootstrap 3's icons. I tried the transform scale stuff and the problem is it makes the icon larger but it doesn't make it thicker which is what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll use that as a workaround while I keep looking. Thanks again!

Comment: @onzinsky maybe `text-shadow` without blur value could be the solution

Comment: that’s a better workaround indeed! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solution with tools of the official standard. Maybe you should put `transform: scale(2)` at the beginning of your answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked with me when working with react

stroke: white;
stroke-width: 3px;